# How to fix size of elevated button inside a list view?

Tags: flutter, button

I try to fix the width size of my button but each time it takes all the available space in the width of the screen. I attach the code of the button :

```
ConstrainedBox(
              constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(const Size(200, 35)),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  types.Room room =
                      await FirebaseChatCore.instance.createRoom(user!);
                  if (!mounted) return;
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => ChatPage(room: room),
                    ),
                  );
                },
                child: Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: const Text(
                    "Send Message",
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

I tried to change the container by SizedBox but the same error has occurred.

Thanks for your help,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your ElevatedButton with SizedBox and then Further wrap it up with UnconstainedBox widget if the Button still doesn't get the explicit size.

```
UnconstrainedBox(
    child: SizedBox(
        width: 140,height:45,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            //onTap function define here
          },
          child: const Text('Send Message'),
        ),
      )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can resize your Elevated button with SizedBox like this:

```
SizedBox(
        width: 250,
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            //onTap function define here
          },
          child: const Text('Send Message'),
        ),
      )
```

Comment: I had already try with sized box but the result is the same of container or elevated button style

Answer (score 0):

`ElevatedButton` have style parameter that use `ElevatedButton.styleFrom`. In which we have three parameter for size.

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  child: Text('Button'),
  onPressed: () {},
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    fixedSize: Size(150, 150), //For Fixed Size
    minimumSize: Size(100, 100), //For Minimum Size of button
    maximumSize: Size(200, 200), //For Maximum Size of button
  ),
),
```

To change only the width, use `Size.fromWidth(100)`.

Comment: I removed my container, and I added a style field with ElavatedButton.styleFrom() but my button width size take always all my width screen. The height can be updated but not the width and I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you add code of the `ElevatedButton`'s parent. Is it wraped in rows?